# Java swing repainting while computing: animating sorting algorithm

Tags: java, swing, sorting, animation, event-dispatch-thread

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0cNsmjK33E

I want to develop something similar to the link above using Java Swing. I have the sorting method and did while repaint but when I triggered the sorting, instead of showing the bars slowly sorting itself, it freezes and then unfreezes when the array has been fully sorted.

How do I fix this? 
Edit: sorry forgot about the codes. its a very simple gui. and another class for sorting which sorts the whole array

```
public class SortGUI {
JFrame frame;
int frameWidth = 1000, frameHeight = 1000;
int panelWidth, panelHeight;
DrawPanel panel;
JPanel panel2;
JScrollPane scroll;
JViewport view;

static int[] S = new int[50000];

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SortGUI app = new SortGUI();
    initializeArray();        
    app.go(); 
}

public static void initializeArray()
{
         for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
     S[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 16581375);
     }
}

public void go() throws InterruptedException {
    //Frame
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

    //panel
    panel = new DrawPanel();
    scroll = new JScrollPane(panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


    //Layout
    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.addKeyListener(new keyListener());

    while(true)
    {               
        panel.repaint();
    }
   }


public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{   
    public DrawPanel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50000,930));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {          
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
        {
            int red = S[i] / 65025;
            int green = (S[i] > 65025)? S[i] % 65025 : 0;
            int blue = green;
            blue %= 255;
            green /= 255;

             g.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue));
            g.fillRect(i, 900 - (S[i] / 18500), 1, S[i] / 18500);
        }
    }
}

  public class keyListener implements KeyListener{


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
      if(ke.getKeyChar() == '1')
      {
   sorter.bubbleSort(S);
      }
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) { 
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Where is code? Please share for sooner help?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: sorry, added the codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Note: I started writing this before the question was deleted</sub>

Most likely your using some looping mechanism and praying that each iteration, the ui with be updated. That's a wrong assumption. The UI will *not* be update until the loop is finished. What you are doing is what we refer to as blocking the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)

See [How to use a Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Make *"iterative"* updates in the ActionListener call back. For instance, if you want to animate a sorting algorithm, you need to determine what needs to be updated per *"iteration"* of the timer callback. Then each iteration repaint the ui.

So your Timer timer could look something like

```
Timer timer  = new Timer(40, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (sortingIsDone()) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        } else {
            sortOnlyOneItem();
        }
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Your `sortOnlyOneItem` method should only, well, perform a sort for just one item. And have some sort of flag to check if the sorting is done, then stop the timer.

---

Other notes:

- You should be calling `super.paintComponent` in the `paintComponent` method, if you aren't going to paint the background yourself. Generally I always do though.

---

Here's a complete example. I'm glad you figured it out on your own. I was working on this example before I saw that you got it.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SelectionSortAnimate extends JPanel {

    private static final int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 20;
    private static final int DIM_W = 400;
    private static final int DIM_H = 400;
    private static final int HORIZON = 350;
    private static final int VERT_INC = 15;
    private static final int HOR_INC = DIM_W / NUM_OF_ITEMS;

    private JButton startButton;
    private Timer timer = null;
    private JButton resetButton;

    Integer[] list;
    int currentIndex = NUM_OF_ITEMS - 1;

    public SelectionSortAnimate() {
        list = initList();

        timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isSortingDone()) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    startButton.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    sortOnlyOneItem();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list = initList();
                currentIndex = NUM_OF_ITEMS - 1;
                repaint();
                startButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        add(startButton);
        add(resetButton);
    }

    public boolean isSortingDone() {
        return currentIndex == 0;
    }

    public Integer[] initList() {
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[NUM_OF_ITEMS];
        for (int i = 1; i <= nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i - 1] = i;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(nums));
        return nums;
    }

    public void drawItem(Graphics g, int item, int index) {
        int height = item * VERT_INC;
        int y = HORIZON - height;
        int x = index * HOR_INC;
        g.fillRect(x, y, HOR_INC, height);
    }

    public void sortOnlyOneItem() {
        int currentMax = list[0];
        int currentMaxIndex = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j <= currentIndex; j++) {
            if (currentMax < list[j]) {
                currentMax = list[j];
                currentMaxIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if (currentMaxIndex != currentIndex) {
            list[currentMaxIndex] = list[currentIndex];
            list[currentIndex] = currentMax;
        }
        currentIndex--;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            drawItem(g, list[i], i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DIM_W, DIM_H);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort");
                frame.add(new SelectionSortAnimate());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you write this also for bubble sort and insertion sort?

Comment: Using Timer worked for my progressBar when nothing else could. You simply have to re-write your code to iterate instead of loop as he said.